Tangent space as submanifold of tangent bundle
If $M$ is smooth manifold and $E:=TM$ its tangent bundle, then $E$ itself is also a smooth manifold, and it can be decomposed as
$$
E=\bigcup_{p\in M}T_pM
$$
Consider the bundle projection $\pi:E\to M$. The fiber $E_p$ of $E$ at each point is the tangent space $E_p=T_pM$, and it is the preimage of $\pi^{-1}(p)$. I want to use the regular level set theorem to show that $E_p$ is a submanifold of $E$. To apply the theorem, I need to show that $p$ is regular point in $M$, this means the differential $\pi_{*,v}: T_vE\to T_pM$ is surjective. But how should I do this, since I have no information about the tangent space of $E$?

When constructing the tangent bundle, in order to say it is a smooth manifold, you need to give it an atlas. Given this atlas, there is a rather simple description of $\pi_{*,v}$ in the correct local coordinates on $TM$ and $M$.

Observe that a local trivialization of the bundle $T_*M$ is also a coordinate chart on the manifold  $T_*M$. After that, it is straightforward to show that $\pi$ is a submersion.
